# select rows that are equal to a numpy nd array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Panda's Dataframe **"pat_data"** which looks like this:
(the columns f1 to f5 contain binary numbers)

```
Stay_id | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5
----------------------------------
1011    |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 0
1011    |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 | 1
.
.
.
1011    |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 | 1
```

and a subset of values saved as numpy nd-array like this:

```
[[0 1 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
.....]
```

what I want to do is to select the rows from **"pat_data"** where the row vector (ex. for the first row,  the vector is [1 0 1 1 0]) is equal to one of the vectors in the numpy array. For example, the first and last row from the data frame are found in the nd-array so I should have them selected.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is binary, you can use `isin` with a little trick:

```
# set up
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,1,1]],
                 columns=[f'f{i}' for i in '12345'])

arr = np.array([[0,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])

# is in:
s = (df[[f'f{i}' for i in '12345']]
         .mul(2**np.arange(5)).sum(1)           # convert binary to 5-bit int
         .isin((arr * (2**np.arange(5))).sum(1) # convert binary to 5-bit int
              )
    )
df[s]
```

Output:

```
   f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
0   1   0   1   1   0
2   0   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert DataFrame to a numpy array using `.values` in this way:

```
data = pat_data.values
```

I'll call your nd-array as `query`. Then, the result you wish is:

```
pairwise_compare = data == query[:, np.newaxis, :]
result = pairwise_compare.all(axis=2).any(axis=0)
```

**What Happened:** We used [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to speed up comparison. Suppose that `data.shape` is (n, k), and `query.shape` is (q, k). (Also, `query[:, np.newaxis, :].shape` is (q, 1, k)).

Then `pairwise_compare.shape` (because of broadcasting) will be (q, n, k). It represents equality of *each element* of each row of `query` and each row of `data`! After that, we select results in which `all` elements are equal, and then we select queries match `any` row in `query`.

Comment: When I try this, I simply get a 1-D array of `[True, True, True,...,True]` with length equal to `query.shape[0]`.  It does not return the desired matching rows.

Comment: You are right @sh37211 . There was a mistake in selecting the axis for `any`. I edited the answer.